# How to validate radio button in html using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

how can i validate the input of radio button?
Currently,i doing a survey form using radio button. I have try many way to validate the radio but all the code are unusable. Anyone can help?TQ. 
Below is my code

```js
var f = document.frmSubmit;    

        var radios = document.getElementsByName('appbk')

     for (var i = 0; i < radios.length; i++) {
         if (document.getElementById("appbk") == false) {
         alert('Remarks has exceeded allowable radio characters.');
         f.appbk.focus();
         return false; // checked
     }
     }

        if (f.FEEDBACK_MSG.value != "" ) { 
         if (f.FEEDBACK_MSG.value.length > 500 ){   
    bootbox.alert('Remarks has exceeded allowable maximum characters.');
    f.FEEDBACK_MSG.focus();
    return false;
   } 
  }

        return true;
        document.getElementById("btnsubmit").disabled = true;
    }
```

```html
<tr>
  <td><div class="text2">Appointment Booking </div></td>
  <td><div class="text3">
   <span style="margin:0 30px;"><input type="radio" id="appbk1" name="appbk" value="1"><lable>1</lable></span>
   <span style="margin:0 30px;"><input type="radio" id="appbk2" name="appbk" value="2"><lable>2</lable></span>
   <span style="margin:0 30px;"><input type="radio" id="appbk3" name="appbk" value="3"><lable>3</lable></span>
   <span style="margin:0 30px;"><input type="radio" id="appbk4" name="appbk" value="4"><lable>4</lable></span>
   <span style="margin:0 30px;"><input type="radio" id="appbk5" name="appbk" value="5"><lable>5</lable></span>
  </div>
  </td>
 </tr>
```

Comment: `id` should be unique

Comment: ok, what should i do next after i change the id?

Comment: by validating you mean that there should be at least one radio button selected?

Comment: no what i mean is nothing is selected

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/41e5stav/

Comment: @Rayon... check my fiddle...We did the same think...That much loops is needed to check one selected radio button?

Comment: @nisar, But __`jQuery`__ is not tagged mate!

Comment: @Rayon..I did't see it...ok..lets he carry on...

Comment: it work on one question radio button selection but when i put two more question, all message box  is show.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this....
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dg3yxLfr/)

```
$('.submit').click(function(e){
if($('input[name="myRadio"]:checked', '#myForm').val()!==undefined){
alert('submited');
}
else{
alert('enter your choice');
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

id should be unique and you can ge radio button value (true or false) using document.getElementById('id of radio button').checked or you can travel array radios like radios[i].checked==false    instead of  document.getElementById("appbk") == false

Answer (score 0):

This depends on when you want to validate, however, on the click of your forms submit button, I would do a function onclick for the button. If any field checks aren't selected (using a for loop and boolean set to true on check), then prevent the default button action of a href and instead display a div with an error message in. This way, the form will also keep its previous data.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the link posted by `RAYON DABRE` as his code is working perfectly.

OR

You just have to check the records selected or not based on your requirement. A sample code has been added for your reference

```
function funcheckvalidate() {
        if (document.getElementById('btnSubmit').checked == true) {
            alert('button checked');
        } else if (document.getElementById('btnSubmit').checked  == false) {
            alert('button not checked');
        }
    }
```

HTML for the same

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="text2">
                Appointment Booking
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="text3">
                <span style="margin: 0 30px;">
                    <input type="radio" id="appbk1" name="appbk" value="1"><lable>1</lable></span>
                <span style="margin: 0 30px;">
                    <input type="radio" id="appbk2" name="appbk" value="2"><lable>2</lable></span>
                <span style="margin: 0 30px;">
                    <input type="radio" id="appbk3" name="appbk" value="3"><lable>3</lable></span>
                <span style="margin: 0 30px;">
                    <input type="radio" id="appbk4" name="appbk" value="4"><lable>4</lable></span>
                <span style="margin: 0 30px;">
                    <input type="radio" id="appbk5" name="appbk" value="5"><lable>5</lable></span>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="button" id="btnSubmit" value="submit" style="width: 75px;" onclick="return funcheckvalidate()" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: ya i know but only work for me on one question only the rest cannot